# android automotive, where is the source?

Tags: android, automotive

I have a board here running TDA4VH from TI, and I want to check if I can use android automotive OS on it, but I can not find the source for it, or links explaining how to get it.
Does anybody have a link, or any information how to set it up?
BTW, there are chances it is not supported, but I still want to have the source code for Android automotive OS.

Br, Mircea

Answer (score 0):

You can access it [here](https://source.android.com/).
You can search for [AOSP](https://source.android.com/docs/automotive) at the relevant address.

Comment: i got that much, but all I find is the android source code, and I need the automotive source code, or at least some explanation on how to get the source to be automotive android.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and sync normal AOSP source code.
The only thing difference here is when you select Target to build

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_car_x86_64
```

After that you can refer yo google guide line https://developer.android.com/training/cars
It not much info but mostly it same with normal Android App/services developments. It only hard when you trying to integrate this with Vehicle Networking and other ECU which google never specify